# In R, is there a built in function for iterating a function n times?

Tags: r, loops

Suppose I have a variable `x` and a function `f`. I would like to perform `f` on `x`, then again on the result, `n` times.

I have built a simple function for this:

```
iterate <- function(x, f, n) {

    assertthat::assert_that(n >= 0)

    if (n > 0) {

        for (i in 1:n) {

            x <- f(x)
        }
    }

    x
}
```

Which works as follows:

```
iterate(256, f = sqrt, n = 3)
```

Is this already built into R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a functional programming approach, with `Reduce` and `Compose` from `functional` package. The idea is to create the list of function you want and chain them using `Compose`. You simply apply this function to `x` afterwards.

```
x = 256
n = 3
f = sqrt

library(functional)

Reduce(Compose, replicate(n, f))(x)
#[1] 2
```

Or use `freduce` from `magrittr`:

```
library(magrittr)

freduce(x, replicate(n, f))
#[1] 2
```

Comment: I think my existing solution is easier to read - good to know the alternatives, however.

Comment: I find Reduce very explicit - imperative versus func prog ;) What matters is that both works!

Comment: But which one is faster?  :-)